# Update a value in a array of objects

Tags: powershell

If I have an array of objects like

```
$Results = @(
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    Email = $_.email
    Type  = $Type
  }
  # ...
)
```

and I want to update the 100th `$results.type` value from X to y. I thought this code would be

```
$results.type[100] = 'Hello'
```

But this is not working and I am not sure why?

Comment: `$results[100].type = 'Hello'`

Comment: yeah ? If that works I will be mad.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen change to answer, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Results.Type[100] = 'Hello'` doesn't work because *`$Results.Type` isn't real!*

`$Results` is an array. It contains a number of objects, each of which have a `Type` property. The array itself also has a number of properties, like its `Length`.

When PowerShell sees the `.` member invocation operator in the expression `$Results.Type`, it first attempts to resolve any properties of the array itself, but since the `[array]` type doesn't have a `Type` property, it instead tries to enumerate the items contained in the array, and invoke the `Type` member on each of them. This feature is known as *member enumeration*, and produces a new one-off array containing the values enumerated.

Change the expression to:

```
$Results[100].Type = 'Hello'
```

Here, instead, we reference the 101st item contained in the `$Results` array (which *is real*, it already exists), and overwrite the value of the `Type` property of that object.

Answer (score 0):

@MathiasR.Jessen answered this. The way I was indexing the array was wrong.

the correct way is `$results[100].type = 'Hello'`